# Using Sublime Text with cmake (build system)

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, sublimetext

I am using Sublime Text in Ubuntu and learning OpenCV. Until today, I was using Sublime Text to write and save the code, and using Terminal for compiling.

I am compiling with the following code:

```
cmake .
make
./a.out
```

But for fast processing, I am trying to make my build system and I want to make this all automatically by pressing `Ctrl + B`

I've tried the following code in a custom build system but it fails:

```
{
    "cmd": ["cmake ."],
    "cmd": ["make"],
    "cmd": ["./a.o"],
    "selector": "source.c++",
    "shell": true,

    "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["cl", "/Fo${file_path}", "/O2", "$file"],
        "selector": "source.c++",
        "shell": true
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only have one `"cmd"` key in your build system. Please read [the docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) for more information. Instead, you can concatenate your commands using the `&&` operator:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["cmake .", "&&", "make", "&&", "./a.out"],
    "selector": "source.c++",
    "shell": true,
}
```

Since you're on Linux, you don't need the Windows stuff at all.

Comment: It works without the quotes very well, thank you ( "cmd": ["cmake . &&  make && ./a.out"])

Answer (score 7):

You can use cmake to create a sublime project. Just execute

```
cmake -G "Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles" .
```

I don't know if it works for subime text 3 since I don't have it installed

Comment: It works with Sublime Text 3 as well. Thanks! Now, how to debug using Sublime ;-)?

Comment: look at sublime gdb, it easy and works great: https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeGDB

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [MattDMo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426065/mattdmo), I have built a build system that works properly, here it is:

```
{
    "cmd": ["cp /home/as/Documents/c++/opencv/CMakeLists.txt ${file_path} &&  cmake . && make && ./project"], "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c++",
    "shell": true
}
```

It copies the CMakeLists.txt (Which is a default CMakeList.txt I have prepared to be suitable with every project) to the current project directory and runs the project.

Additionally, CMakeLists.txt includes the following text:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( project )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( project main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( project ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

I hope that will run all of OpenCV projects!